# May we choose the confidence interval's width or credible interval'swidth based on a loss-function or cross-validation?

Tags: confidence-interval, cross-validation, standard-error, loss-functions, credible-interval

May we choose the confidence interval or credible interval based on an empirical risk loss-function?

I think we blindly generate the width intervals without any optimization or rely on some asymptotically correct notion of standard error.

I know the point estimates are based on loss-functions, but the intervals seem to be lacking in quality.

Is it possible to estimate standard error using cross-validation?

Comment: What? There is no "loss function" in a confidence interval estimation, what are you referring to?

Comment: A measure of quality of the bias and variance of the interval among all possible intervals. I mean there's no way I know to compare the credible interval and confidence interval. what is alpha?

Comment: I see, you are asking if you can select $\alpha$ from all the possible values in $[0,1]$ based on some automated procedure?